# ¿Qué es una Unidad de Traducción en C++?

Tags: c++

He estado viendo un video de el canal "[The Cherno](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQ-W1KE9EYfdxhL6S4twUNw)" llamado: "[How the C++ Compiler Works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tIqpEmWMLI)", y más o menos en el minuto [4:14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tIqpEmWMLI&t=254s), menciona algo llamado: "Unidad de Traducción";

en ese momento me hice esta pregunta:

> ¿Qué es una Unidad de Traducción en C++?

De ahí, comencé a investigar acerca de eso...

### Que he intentado

He buscado por esta [página](https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/10204/que-es-una-unidad-de-traduccion-en-c) y vi una respuesta que dice lo siguiente:

> > De acuerdo con [el estándar de c++](http://www.efnetcpp.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14882): Una unidad de traducción es la unidad básica de la compilación en C++. Consta de el contenido de un único archivo de origen, además de los contenidos de los archivos de encabezado directa o indirectamente por ella, menos de esas líneas que fueron ignorados uso de condicionales de preprocesamiento declaraciones.

Esa respuesta me dejó entre medias, casi no entendí... También busqué por otras partes, pero no pondré sus enlaces, porque creo que su explicación acerca de este tema no se entiende...

Comment: La unidad de traduccion es el archivo final que traduce el compilador, en ese "archivo final" se incluye el codigo de cada archivo de cabecera y tambien las macros expandidas (con `#define`).